# Put string query in beetween the path in React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, flux

I am creating one app using reactJS. I am defining routing  by react-router.

sample code is below:

```
<Router history={browserHistory()}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="taco/:name" component={Taco} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

but I want to use something like this:

```
 <Route path="taco?yourchoice/:name" component={Taco} />
```

but I am not able to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I dont think you need to state the query parameters there. React-router injects a 'location' property on the root component

Comment: So you want `taco?yourchoice=value`  right?

Answer (score 0):

`path="taco?yourchoice/:name` is not a valid path. Because you include the forward slash between `yourchoice` and `:name`, I am not positive if you are trying to place a path segment after the query or capture the `yourchoice` query parameter value.

In the case of the former, you cannot place a path segment after the search segment of a URL and you will need to reorder the path. For the latter, React Router does not take into account the search string when it is matching the current location to route paths. However, the location will be parsed and the query parameters will be available on the `location` object (which is injected as a prop into the `<Route>`'s `component`.

So, given the route:

```
<Route path="taco" component={Taco} />
```

When the user navigates to the URL:

```
example.com/taco?yourchoice=fish
```

The `Taco` component will be rendered and one of its props will be `location`.

```
class Taco extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { query } = this.props.location

    return <div>A {query.yourchoice} taco</div>
  }
}
```